# How can i place a positioned absolute div perfectly pointing towards a link and it doesn't move even when the browser window is resized?

Tags: html, css

I have a very teasing issue. I have a div positioned absolutely to a point. But when i resize the window, it is moved to other place and not pointed towards where i set it before. How can i resolve this problem?

Here is my HTML -

```
<div style="position:relative;">
<div id="intro_message">
content
</div>
</div>
```

And the CSS for "intro_message" div -

```
#intro_message
{
   position: absolute;
   left: 322px;
   top: 0;
   padding: 20px;
   width: 505px;
}
```

You can clearly see even i used relative position to its parent it still doesn't work for me.

**EDIT -**

Here from 'clearly see..." means if i would have not tell that i used relative positioning then everyone here would suggest me to use it. Therefore i told you all in advance.

**EDIT 2 -**

@David - After reading you solution, i understood it, actually i had to do one little but crucial change in my css. Now, i have following css for my main container div -

```
margin: auto;
position: relative;
width: 505px;
```

and for the inner div #intro_message i have changed some values to position it fine -

```
#intro_message
{
   position: absolute;
   left: -137px;
   top: -4px;
   padding: 20px;
   width: 505px;
}
```

Now it is placed nicely pointing towards a link where i wanted it to be. On resize it still well, but when i go on resizing it is moved again -

on full window by default -

[image]

on resize - issue arises again -

[image]

So how to solve it?

Comment: *You can clearly see...* - I don't think so, at least there is nothing wrong with the code, It's just not clear on what you actually want here.

Comment: what do you mean by perfectly even? or you meant centered?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you do not **actually** want the div to be fixed to a coordinate point, because that is what absolute positioning relative to the window does: resizing the page will move **everything *but*** the div. So you must want it to be fixed relative to the document.

---

**Though you mentioned** you tried relative positioning and it didn't work for you, that is actually the answer to this problem. *You used it incorrectly.*

### Let me explain:

Divs naturally fill the entire width of their parent containers, so placing your absolutely positioned element inside a plain div essentially did nothing. In order for it to matter, you need to have the parent container be in the right spot. I would assume that your parent container would probably be centered inside your page and be a fixed width.

To do this, you can create your div and assign a width and automatic margins to center it:

```
div[c]{
    width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

As you can see in the following fiddle, both the div positioned relative to the window and the div positioned relative to the yellow div end up in the same place because the div has the full width of the page, but the div positioned relative to the blue div is moved where it should be and will stay there if you resize the page.

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xF7Nd/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Just use this css:

```
<style type="text/css">
#intro_message
{
   position: absolute;
   left: 30%;
   top: 0;
   padding: 4%;
   width: 505px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS

```
.contains{
position:relative;
margin:0 auto;
width:900px;//or whatever you want
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="contains">
<div id="intro_message">
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not clearly define your problem so i assume that you have problem in left postion.
I think when you are resize the window inner div will be plot  left will be change according to you.
There is no problem regarding to position but your logic was not cleared.
if you want left inner div perfectly than use "percentage" rather than "pixel"

example:

```
#intro_message
{
   position: absolute;
   left: 30%;
   top: 0;
   padding: 20px;
   width: 505px;
}
```